# How to loop through json Object using foreach using PHP?

Tags: php, json

How do I use for each to access and print the participant name. The Json object is "particpants:name" and it gets populated when uploaded with a tokenized file. I know the tokenized file does create a successful JSON obj. It is inside the foreach loop that gives me trouble.

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\nkmoorth\EthicsRound1.php on line 100

```
 protected function setMiddleHTML()
{
  //temp

  $this->html.='<div id="middleContainer">';
  $this->jsonObj = json_decode($_POST['fileContents']);
    $count=sizeOf($this->jsonObj->{'participants'}) -1;
  for($i =0; $i<$count; $i++) //should be numSections
   {
    $this->html .= '<tables class="section">';
      foreach($this->jsonObj->{'participants'} as $index => $value)
      {
      $this->html.='<td>' . $this->jsonObj->participants[$value].'</td> ';
      } // foreach
    $this->html .= '</table>';



  }// for    } // setMiddleHTML()

          $this->html.='</div>'; // closing middle Container;
 }
```

Comment: gives me the trouble too when you are printing $this->jsonObj->participants[$value] instead of just $value. Btw give us a dump of your object.

Comment: Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key. please give the dump of your array object.

Answer (score 1):

1) $json is a string you need to decode it first.

```
$json = json_decode($json);
```

2) you need to loop through the object and get its members

```
foreach($json as $obj){
   echo $obj->name;
   .....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying the wrong index in this code

```
foreach($this->jsonObj->{'participants'} as $index => $value)
{
    // $this->html.='<td>' . $this->jsonObj->participants[$value].'</td> ';

    // instead
    $this->html.='<td>' . $this->jsonObj->participants[$index].'</td> ';

    //or
    //$this->html.='<td>' . $value.'</td> ';

} // foreach
```